# Placeholder in UITextField is misplaced, when orientation is changed

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have UITextField along with placeholder.I am using ios 5.0.When I change orientation from portrait to landscape or vice-versa, the cursor is shifting and overlapping placeholder.Can anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using Interface Builder, you should check the autoresizing mask you are using. the animation is very self explanatory. If you are not using  IB, then you should layout your subviews programmatically after rotation has taken place.

PS: you should start accepting answers to your questions.

Comment: I am creating views programmatically and using autoresizing mask too,the textfield width is increasing and text is also coming proper but for placeholder it is shifting.Sorry for not accepting answer will accept now.